# Build validation rules for item DisplayName property

Tags: sitecore

I'm working on a multi-language solution in Sitecore and want to use the DisplayName property of an item to represent the URL to allow for language-specific URLs.

I've set the `useDisplayName` web.config property to true as shown below

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" 
         alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"
         encodeNames="true"
         type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel"
         addAspxExtension="false"
         shortenUrls="true"
         languageEmbedding="asNeeded"
         languageLocation="filePath"
         useDisplayName="true" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

I've also been playing with the `<encodeNameReplacements>` section which can replace `%20` with a hyphen in the URL to give nice clean URLs - this is done with the following for those who are interested:

```
<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />
```

All very good, except that Sitecore breaks if a user enters a hyphen within a DisplayName with the above setting turned on....  If I turn the above setting off, then I have to ensure that users enter nice hyphen separated values for the DisplayName otherwise we start seeing nasty `%20`s again in the URL...

So, is there a way to validate the DisplayName property to either disallow or allow hyphens being used?

Or, even better, is there a way to hook into whatever code is executed when the encodeNameReplacements thing happens? This would be ideal, as I could allow users to enter whatever they like for DisplayName, then just sanitise this value on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution for this, but it will require some coding and it's quite complex.
I have used this kind of solution in many projects before and it's the only way of solving this, that i'm aware of.

You don't want to really replace spaces with hyphens when saving the item, because it's not user friendly.
My solution works at runtime.

First get rid of the `<replace>` rule you added.

Then create your own `LinkProvider` (inherit from Sitecore's default provider).
Inside the LinkProvider create a method to "normalize" the item's displayname (e.g. replace spaces for hyphens), let's call this method `NormalizeDisplayName()`. Make it public and static cause you will need it later.

So now you have managed to let Sitecore replace all spaces with hyphens in links. The rest you can still configure using the default provider options (addAspxExtension="false" useDisplayName="true", etc)

Next up is the `ItemResolver`: Sitecore's default ItemResolver is not going to recognize the item path anymore so you are going to add your own ItemResolver to fix this.

Create a class that inherits from `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor` and configure it to be used in the `<httpRequestBegin>` pipeline **after** the default ItemResolver.

Now, when the itemresolver is processed you will first split up the requested itempath (let's assume that "/category-name/subitem-name" was requested).
Starting from the siteroot (which can be pulled from `Sitecore.Context.Site`), loop through all children while normalizing their item names using your `NormalizeDisplayName()` method you created earlier, until you find one that matches the part of your item path.

So in this case, loop through the children of your Home item until you find one that matches normalized displayname "category-name". Then do the same thing for the children of that item until you find the item with normalized displayname "subitem-name".

This way you can resolve the requested item and it **will also work if the original displayname already contained hyphens**!

I'm sorry that I can't give you complete code examples as it's quite complex and is not limited to just the above things. You also need to think about redirecting if the URL is not properly formatted and make exceptions for master/core database to prevent Sitecore from breaking.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.  I like the idea of doing everything on the fly and in particular, not renaming stuff after a user has saved.  Is there not a bit of a performance hit from recursing through the content tree like this though?

Comment: It can be a performance issue yes, but only if you have folders with lot's of items (say over 200) in your site structure which is always strongly discouraged, no matter what.
If you have a huge site structure, you can always implement caching in the ItemResolver though. This implementation has been used for several high-traffic websites without causing any performance problems!

Answer (score 0):

If you see the source in .net reflector (Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.SetDisplayName) there are no pipelines that runs.

You could make a Saving event, making the display name, as you want replacing hypen with a space

```
public void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

        item.Appearance.DisplayName = item.Appearance.DisplayName.Replace("-", " ");
    }
```

Just a quick example of the event

Comment: Hi, I was also thinking of something along these lines, but was hoping for a solution which applied at runtime, rather than relying on the save event - users might find it a bit strange that their CMS is automatically changing the name that they've set for something.

Comment: I was thinking the same, and tried to come up with a solution.
But there a many places in Sitecore, where display names could be set.
Custom commands, item generation etc. Where you cant code a hook, to validate the input